# Question about include statements and details in Arduino.h file from core library

Tags: uploading, core-libraries, avr-gcc, gcc

This is more of a C/C++ question. However the files I am asking about are a part of the Arduino library.

In */arduino-1.6.5-r5/hardware/arduino/avr/cores/arduino/Arduino.h* :

```
#ifndef Arduino_h
#define Arduino_h

#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <math.h>

#include <avr/pgmspace.h>
#include <avr/io.h>
#include <avr/interrupt.h>

#include "binary.h"

#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C"{
#endif
```

How are these blocks found at compile time in the main sketch?

```
#include <avr/pgmspace.h>
#include <avr/io.h>
#include <avr/interrupt.h>
```

Does `#include <avr/somelibrary.h>` mean that this is a standard library from either *avr-g++* or *avr-gcc*? As opposed to a standard g++ or gcc compiler?

One last question, how can there be an *Arduino.h* without an *Arduino.c*? I searched through the project but could not find an *Arduino.c*. All of these are probably stupid questions, as I am in the process of learning C/C++. I am completely new to it.

Comment: why the two down-votes on this recently? And 3 months later...

Answer (score 1):

> Does `#include <avr/somelibrary.h>` mean that this is a standard library from either *avr-g++* or *avr-gcc*? As opposed to a standard g++ or gcc compiler?

No. It simply means that the compiler should check both its built-in include paths as well as any passed via the `-I` command line option (or its local equivalent) for a file called "avr/somelibrary.h". That AVR GCC knows where AVR Libc is located is incidental.

> One last question, how can there be an *Arduino.h* without an *Arduino.c*?

There is no obligation to match each header file with a .c/.cc/.cpp file, or vice versa.

Comment: So the function signatures within *Arduino.h* are defined by the libraries referenced, via the include statements shown in OP?

Comment: The headers referenced, yes.

Comment: Suppose there is an include in an include, so to speak. Would the header file pick up functions to the second level?

Comment: Does avr/someLibrary.h mean to that someLibrary.h is contained in a directory called avr?

Comment: @skywalker: That is correct.

Comment: Maybe there is no obligation to match a header file with a .c/.cc/.cpp file, but the functions have to exist somewhere when you call them

Answer (score 0):

I think after all this time, you may found the answers for your question.

But to add some information to this topic incase if anyone opened this question.

> Does #include  mean that this is a standard library
>   from either avr-g++ or avr-gcc? As opposed to a standard g++ or gcc
>   compiler?

Yes, what is included with `avr/` is related to avr standard libraries, which is also found in avr standard compilers.

> One last question, how can there be an Arduino.h without an Arduino.c?

Because, as Mr @Ignacio Vazquez-Abrams answered that there's no obligation for connecting the header file for anything else. You can write multiple header files and use them for one source file.